# Select query to retrieve rows with null values

Tags: postgresql, select, null, aggregate

I need to retrieve data from a table even if one of the fields has null value. Here's an example:

```
Select name, SUM(credit) as credit
From expenses
Where name like 'vendor0%'
and date like '2013%'
Group by name
Order by name asc
```

This example retrieves `name` and `SUM(credit)` only when `credit` has values. I need to retrieve all from `name` even if `credit` has no value at all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

> This example retrieves only "name" and the "SUM(credit)", when the
>   "credit" has values.

The query you presented **will** retrieve a row for every present `name`, even if *all* associated `credit` columns are `NULL`. You get a row with a NULL value for `SUM(credit)` then. Null values are just ignored by the aggregate function `sum()`:

You only get **no row** for a particular name if no row for that name exists in the table `expenses` for the given `WHERE` expressions.

I am **assuming** you want
.. only names matching `'vendor0%'`
.. but all of those, even if they have no expenses in 2013.

Your query could work like this:

```
SELECT name, SUM(CASE WHEN date LIKE '2013%' THEN credit END) AS credit
FROM   expenses
WHERE  name LIKE 'vendor0%'
GROUP  BY name
ORDER  BY name
```

`CASE` defaults to `NULL` if no `ELSE` branch is given.
Aside: You shouldn't store date / time values as text. Use an [appropriate type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), it has many advantages.
And don't use "name" or "date" as identifiers. "name" is not a descriptive name and "date" is a [reserved word in standard SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and a function and base type name in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `SUM(credit)` with `SUM(COALESCE(credit,0))` or `SUM(ISNULL(credit,0))`.

You don't say what database you are using, so you may not have both the above functions available. If you have both, see your documentation or run benchmarks to see which (if either) performs better.

Comment: Oracle has NVL()

Comment: Very sorry, i use Postgresql 9. Thank you.

Comment: [`sum()` ignores `NULL` values anyway](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html). The only effect: you get `0` instead of `NULL` for groups with only NULL values. But that could be had cheaper with `COALESCE(sum(...), 0)` and doesn't seem to be the problem to begin with. Rows seem to be missing, and `COALESCE()` won't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for solve your problem,

```
Select name
From expenses
Where name like 'vendor0%'
and date like '2013%'
and credit IS NULL
Group by name
Order by name asc
```